# Composed content css body class with TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, css, tinymce-4

I'm trying to set a composed css class to the content_css parameter of TinyMCE instance.

The css:

```
.page.show {
  background: red;
  padding: 0 0 10px;
}
```

The init JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    content_css : "/css/frontend/screen.css",
    body_class : ".page.show"
 });
</script>
```

But it doesn't work, and the project work on composed css class, and I won't duplicate css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding as a selector (like you do in CSS) have you tried just separating the classes with a space (like you would in html). So you would have the following instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        content_css : "/css/frontend/screen.css",
        body_class : "page show"
    });
</script>
```

I haven't tried this though, but seems like the right idea.